# How to use jsonschema for Loopback remoteMethod?

Tags: jsonschema, loopbackjs, strongloop

In my app I want define JSON schemas for custom API.

For example from: http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Remote+methods#Remotemethods-Example

```
module.exports = function(Person){

    Person.greet = function(msg, cb) {
      cb(null, 'Greetings... ' + msg);
    }

    Person.remoteMethod(
        'greet', 
        {
          accepts: <generate definitions from jsonschema>,
          returns: <generate definitions from jsonschema>
        }
    );
};
```

How to do that?

This is right way?

**MY SOLUTION** - validation decorator + remote method params with object type

```
var validate = require('jsonschema').validate;

bySchema = function (schema) {
  return function (func) {

    return function () {
      var data = arguments[0],
        callback = arguments[1];

      var result = validate(data, schema);

      if (result.errors.length > 0) {
        // some errors in request body
        callback(null, {
          success: false,
          error: 'schema validation error',
        });
        return;
      }
      return func.apply(this, arguments);
    };
  };
};

defaultRemoteArguments = {
  accepts: {
    arg: 'data',
    type: 'object',
    http: function(ctx) {
      return ctx.req.body;
    }
  },
  returns: {
    arg: 'data',
    type: 'object',
    root: true
  }
};
```

Example:

```
Auth.login = bySchema(require('<path to shcemajson json for this request>'))
  (function(data, cb) {
    // process request
  });
Auth.remoteMethod('login', defaultRemoteArguments);
```

In this solution contrib loopback explorer will not be useful, because request/response are objects, not fields...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to do it is to set the `type` in the `returns` attribute to the model name.
In your case you would write:

```
Person.remoteMethod(
        'greet', 
        {
          ...
          returns: {type:'Person', ...}
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your output to match the format accepted by the `returns` property.

```
...
returns: [{arg: "key1", type: "string"}, {arg: "key2", type: "object"}, ...];
...
```